# Keeping code in a render function outside Vs keeping code in return

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component, conditional-rendering

I'd like to know whether we should go for 2nd approach if we just have a few conditional rendering:

1st Approach:

```
const MyComponent = ({ isOpen }) => {
...
return (
   {isOpen && <MyAnotherComponent />}
);
}
```

2nd Approach:

```
const MyComponent = ({ isOpen }) => {
   ...
   const renderComponent = () => {
       if (isOpen) {
       return <MyAnotherComponent />
       }
       
   }

   return (
      renderComponent()
   )
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Where are conditions? And it's better you follow 1st approach which will keep everything as a component in return and not a function call. You can store you component as a variable and then render that variable based on condition.
You can use condition in **JSX** with ternary operator or short-circuiting `condition && <Component/>` and you can also use `map` and other similar approach within **JSX** which will return component

Just don't use function calls within `return` as a component. I personally never encountered any code or project which uses function call.